Regenerate access tokens through refresh token rotation in Next.js between site-changes
So I've implemented refresh-token-rotation with jwt. This works great for api-calls, since when ever I return 401 instead of the data, I can just make the client call the api endpoint to refresh the acces token. But it gets hard when doing so when loading actual web-pages. How can I tell the client to make a request to the endpoint silently and than reload the page?
I tried to send a request with .sendBeacon on the beforeunload event, but since it is non-blocking, it just continouse directly to the page while being unauthenticated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
